# DIV height not 100%

Tags: html, css, opencart

I installed a new module to my Opencart store, but there is a little css bug:

[image: screenshot]

If I click on Filters it is slides down a div with filters, but the slided down div (the red box) height is not 100% (there is a scroll bar).  I would really appreciate any help.

Example: [Cestné bicykle](http://mihalko.secondstyle.sk/cestne-bicykle)

Comment: I just finished a jsfiddle showing how to answer that question you just deleted: http://jsfiddle.net/Yc4eh/  in case it helps :)

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code** to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org) for guidance.

Comment: This question is opencart specific and should be asked on http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77558/opencart instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to set a fixed height, try add this css:

```
.box-filter {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Works on my browser

Answer (score 1):

Remove the height property of `.filter_grouper`

```
.filter_grouper {
  height:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove from `.product-filter` property `overflow:auto` and add `height:140px` or somthing

Answer (score 0):

In your css, remove height on .filter_grouper, so it can be stretched based on content. And remove overflow:auto on .product-filter. That should make it work!